# Make divs which are next to each other take up all vertical space with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a right hand menu with is always the same number of pixels wide and stretches too the bottom of the screen. To the left of that I want a div which fills up the rest of the space. The picture of what I have is shown here:

[image: Red and Green boxes I want to stretch to the bottom of the screen]

The HTML and CSS I am trying out are something like this:

```
<div class=App>
    <div class=Content>
        More Test
    </div>
    <div class=Menu>
        Just Test Text
    </div>
</div>

.App {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Menu {
    background-color: #080;
    flex: 0 0 200px;
}

.Content {
    background-color: #f00;
    flex: auto;   
}
```

Here is a link to a working version of the simple page:

https://jsfiddle.net/tpjsaogx/

Comment: `class=App` -> `class="App"` and also all the others

Comment: @Berto99 While I strongly prefer the latter, the former is not an error unless you're writing XHTML (and it is not relevant to the problem of this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `height: 100%` needs a reference height - the parent elements `html` and `body` won't have any height by themselves. So add this rule:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here's your fiddle adapted accordingly: https://jsfiddle.net/3ck7dypo/

And here's the same code in this snippet:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.App {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Menu {
  background-color: #080;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}

.Content {
  background-color: #f00;
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class=App>
  <div class=Content>
    More Test
  </div>
  <div class=Menu>
    Just Test Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked, but I had to add "display: grid;" to the html and body CSS. For some reason my user agent style sheet was giving it "display: block" which was preventing your fix from working. Other display values might work with specified widths and heights, but I haven't tried them out yet. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's all about relative units. `height:100%` means that this element will take 100% height of its parent. In your case, since `<div class="App">` is the first parent, setting it to 100% height isn't really doing anything. To stretch it to both boxes till the end of the page, all you need to do is give `<div class="App">` a height of 100vh, where vh stands for viewport height. Essentially covering the whole height of the page. You can learn more about css units from MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)